# How to start a spring data hadoop job later?

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, spring-data-hadoop

I'm new for SpringData Hadoop. I checkout some examples from www, such as [1]:https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-data-apache-hadoop-examples/tree/master/mapreduce

All of them are configured to run at start-up:

```
 <hdp:job-runner id="wordCountJobRunner" job-ref="wordCountJob" run-at-startup="true"/>
```

But I want to run the job via a Servlet. How to?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to try this:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/

examples of code you could see the official site, but here is some fragment:

```
// compute a time that is on the next round minute
Date runTime = evenMinuteDate(new Date());

// Trigger the job to run on the next round minute
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .startAt(runTime)
    .build();
```